# tfjs-modelsのpose-detectionでポーズ解析を行っているが、「TypeError: t is not a function」というエラーが出力

Tags: typescript, 機械学習, tensorflow, webpack

現在、tfjs-models/pose-detectionのライブラリを用いて、ポーズ解析のモジュールを追加実装しているところです。下記コードで処理を行っていますが、下記エラーが出力して処理ができない状況です。原因が分からず困っています...
実装コード（一部）

```
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl';
import '@mediapipe/pose';

import * as poseDetection from '@tensorflow-models/pose-detection';

async getData(data: WorkerPortObject) {
    this.video = document.getElementById("video-test") as HTMLVideoElement;

    if (this.video !== null) {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false,
            })
            .then((stream) => {
                this.video.srcObject = stream;
                this.video.play();
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });

        this.video.setAttribute("width", "640");
        this.video.setAttribute("height", "480");

        const model = await poseDetection.SupportedModels.MoveNet;
        const net = await poseDetection.createDetector(model);

        setInterval(() => {
            // detect(net, this.video);
            const pose = net.estimatePoses(this.video);
            console.log(pose);
        }, 100);
    }
```

出力エラー文

```
tf-core.esm.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function
at tf-core.esm.js:17:43052
at tf-core.esm.js:17:41139
at t.scopedRun (tf-core.esm.js:17:41281)
at t.tidy (tf-core.esm.js:17:41033)
at f (tf-core.esm.js:17:43031)
at tf-core.esm.js:17:43365
at t.scopedRun (tf-core.esm.js:17:41281)
at t.runKernelFunc (tf-core.esm.js:17:43174)
at t.runKernel (tf-core.esm.js:17:41712)
at expandDims_ (expand_dims.js:43:12)
```

使用しているnpm packageのバージョン

```
"@tensorflow-models/pose-detection": "^2.0.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^3.20.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^3.20.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^3.20.0",
```

Comment: 情報が断片しかないようでよくわからない部分がありますが、たとえばHTML(scriptタグ)などで `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js` などをロードしてい、[tensorflow.jsを二重にロードしてしまっている](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4944)なんてことはないですか？

Comment: index.htmlからは、cdn経由で外部ライブラリをインポートしていないです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。どうやら同じページ内で使用しているface-api.jsのライブラリとconflictしていたっぽいです。face-api.jsのライブラリを削除したら、無事動作しました。